# Is there an interface between ZED SDK and DeepStream SDK

Tags: nvidia-jetson, nvidia-deepstream, zed-sdk

I have a python script running real time inference on frames garbed from a ZED2i camera
in 1080p@30fps on an nvidia jetson xavier nx.
As I'm trying to boost up the performance I was wondering if there is an interface between ZED SDK and DeepStream SDK?

More info:

- object detector: darknet yolov4tiny 416X416
- jetpack 4.6
- power mode: 20W 6cores

Comment: It would depend on your application and how much you're using ZED SDK.
As DeepStream is based on gstreamer, you can get an image from camera with v4l2src plugin. 
For more specific use involving ZED SDK, you may give a try to Stereolabs plugins : https://github.com/stereolabs/zed-gstreamer

Answer (score 0):

Here is the gstream cmd.

```
gst-launch-1.0 zedsrc stream-type=0 ! videoconvert ! 'video/x-raw,format=(string)YUY2' ! nvvidconv ! 'video/x-raw(memory:NVMM),format=(string)NV12,width=1280,height=720' ! nvvidconv ! mux.sink_0 nvstreammux live-source=1 name=mux batch-size=1 width=1280 height=720 ! nvinfer config-file-path=/opt/nvidia/deepstream/deepstream-6.0/sources/objectDetector_Yolo/config_infer_primary_yoloV3.txt ! nvvideoconvert ! nvdsosd ! nvegltransform ! nveglglessink sync=0
```

[there is a guy out there tried this already](https://github.com/valdivj/gstream_Deep). He provides

- youtube video
- github

Comment: The same pipeline you can get in FastoCloud from Web UI, which will be much easy for your tests.